# Exception while try Date.ParseExact in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to parse this:

```
Date.ParseExact("5/19/2012", "M/d/yyyy", myCultureInfo)
```

In the machine with system date format `MM/dd/yyyy`, it works fine. But in machine with system date format `dd-MMM-yyyy` or any date format other than `MM/dd/yyyy`, it throws exception `String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.`. So how can I get my code above works regardless to system date format?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution

```
Date.ParseExact("5/19/2012", "M/d/yyyy", new Globolization.CultureInfo("en-GB")).toString(myCultureInfo)
```